# Checking User Authorization in Angular 2/4 + API

Tags: angular, authorization, angular2-routing, laravel-5.4

I'm building a angular 2/4 Application that accesses an API in laravel 5.4. 
I have questions in how to check authentication / permissions in the back end through the angular.
I need to check if the user is Logged in and if he has permissions to go ahead.
I’m doing this in Angular through “Guards”.
For example, If the user accesses the “Edit-User” Route in Angular, first, the guard in called ok?
In Guard, it has 1 step:
It makes a http request at Laravel to check if the user can go ahead.
This request gets the callback of the Edit-User Route in Laravel through the Middleware, in other words, The Angular makes a request at Laravel, so, Laravel check if the User is Logged in and has permissions and return a Boolean value, after that, The guard authorize the User access or not the Edit-Route in Angular.
At this time ok, but when the user enters in Edit-Route in Angular, the Angular needs to do one more request to get the user data to show in form, and for do this, Laravel will check on more time if the User is Logged in and his permission.
So, my question is if has a way to think better this situation? Because I’m checking the permissions twice to access one route.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but it looks like any other API auth problem. Why don't you make one call at the init to get the user, and store it in a service or whatever. Then, when navigating to a secured page, you can rely on this user to authorize the access to the page. When the page is loaded, the call that get the data from the API (your second call in your example), will assert that the user actually have the right to access the page.

Answer (score 1):

When first authentication the user, all permissions must received and keep in permission store on the client side. for example you can use [Ng2-Permission](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission) for keep permission in permission store.

After authenticating the user and receiving all of its permissions, we assume that the client is authenticate until not receive `401` or `403` code from response. Authorization check via permissions in the store.